# How do I override an attribute from a super class in a subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, computer-science

I'm pretty sure my code should be working properly, but the tests in my learning platform fail stating that the constructors in my subclasses "should set the description to a value other than 'Unclassified'"

```
Parent Class
```

```
public class Rock
{
   int sampleNumber;
   String description;
   double weight;
  
   public Rock(int sampleNumber, double weight)
   {
       this.sampleNumber = sampleNumber;
       this.description = "Unclassified";
       this.weight = weight;
   }
   public void setSampleNumber( int sampleNumber ){
        this.sampleNumber = sampleNumber;
    }
  
   public int getSampleNumber(){
            return this.sampleNumber;
        }

   public void setDescription( String description ){
        this.description = description;
    }
    
   public String getDescription(){
        return this.description;
        }

   public void setWeight(double weight){
        this.weight = weight;
            }
          
   public double getWeight() {
        return this.weight;
                }

   public String toString()
   {
       return "The number of samples are: "+sampleNumber+
               "\nThe weight of the rock is: "+ weight+
               "\nThe description of rock type is: "+ description;
   }
}
```

One of the child classes (There are 3 and they are pretty much the same)

```
public class SedimentaryRock extends Rock
{
   public SedimentaryRock(int sampleNumber,int weight)
   {
       super(sampleNumber, weight);
   }
   public void setDescription( String description ){
        super.description = description;
    }
  
   public String getDescription(){
            return super.description;
        }
}
```

This is the main class

```
public class DemoRocks
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       IgneousRock rock = new IgneousRock( 2, 200);
       rock.setDescription("andesite");
       System.out.println(rock.toString());
      
       SedimentaryRock rock2= new SedimentaryRock( 3, 300);
       rock2.setDescription("sandstone");
       System.out.println(rock2.toString());
      
       MetamorphicRock rock3=new MetamorphicRock( 4, 400);
       rock3.setDescription("quartzite");
       System.out.println(rock3.toString());
   }

}
```

The output is:

```
The number of samples are: 2
The weight of the rock is: 200.0
The description of rock type is: andesite
The number of samples are: 3
The weight of the rock is: 300.0
The description of rock type is: sandstone
The number of samples are: 4
The weight of the rock is: 400.0
The description of rock type is: quartzite
```

One way to avoid that problem is to set the description in the parent class to " " instead of "Unclassified" but it needs to be set to "unclassified".

I don't know what causes it to behave that way.

Comment: I'd guess the failure is indicating the `SedimentaryRock` constructor should be setting the description, for example, and not the test code.  Also in your implementation, there's no use in overriding the setters/getters.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the test wants you to do below:

```
    public SedimentaryRock(int sampleNumber,int weight) {
           super(sampleNumber, weight);
           super.setDescription("sedimentary");
    }
```

I am assuming that the test wants you to override the property in constructor itself rather than setting it explicitly